# How can I load the solarized-dark theme correctly in Aquamacs from .emacs?

Tags: themes, aquamacs

I load the `solarized-dark` theme in the last line of my `.emacs` files thusly:

```
(load-theme 'solarized-dark t)
```

However, this causes Aquamacs to look like:
[image: bad theme]
If I then load the theme again by entering M-x `load-theme` RET `solarized-dark`, the theme looks correct:
[image: correct theme]
How can I get the theme to load correct from my `.emacs`?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to a legacy startup setting in Aquamacs. You have a couple of options to fix it.

**Patch Aquamacs**

Try the patch [posted here](https://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/issues/127), which *worksforme*.

```
--- Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/macosx/aquamacs-frame-setup.el.orig    2017-04-06 14:38:45.000000000 -0400
+++ Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/macosx/aquamacs-frame-setup.el 2017-04-06 16:30:54.000000000 -0400
@@ -79,7 +79,7 @@
  '((create-frame-min-width 68)
 ;; do not set any fonts here. aquamacs.el takes care of this,
 ;; checking that the fonts actually exist.
-   (default-frame-alist 
+   (initial-frame-alist 
      ((foreground-color . "Black") (background-color . "White") 
       (cursor-type . box) (cursor-color . "Red")
       (vertical-scroll-bars . right)
```

**Edit your init-file**

In your `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` or `~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el` (where ever you load your theme from, add `(setq default-frame-alist nil)` **before** you load your theme, a la:

```
(when window-system
  (when (featurep 'aquamacs)
    (setq default-frame-alist nil))
  (load-theme 'my-new-theme t))
```

Or, more simply:

```
(setq default-frame-alist nil)
(load-theme 'my-new-theme t)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I can no longer test this as when I use Emacs, I use Spacemacs on "emacs-mac" these days.

Comment: @StevenShaw Understandable. This has bugged me for years, and I worked around it by using an old style "color-theme". I only came across your question while doing a little research after deciding to dig into this and find a proper fix.